# how to get dependencies injected in constructors in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

in asp.net-mvc I have the Windsor Controller Factory that injects all the dependencies into the controllers, but how do you get this in Windows Forms ?

for example if have this Form1, how am I going to get an instance of Form1, should I use resolve (which is called ServiceLocator and anti-pattern by some ppl)?

```
public class Form1
{
   private IBarService _barService;

   public Form1(IBarService barService)
   {
       _barService = barService;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in program.cs you should make windsor resolve `Form1`. For the sake of being able to view the form in the designer you add an empty constructor and decorate it with the `Obsolete` attribute.

Comment: The `Obsolete` approach is not working, designer still shows broken

Answer (score 7):

Using **Constructor Injection** for Forms (or other Views in other UI frameworks) is often problematic because the Visual Studio designer expects and assumes a default constructor.

In any case, a Form or other visual Control really ought to be a dumb View without behavior. It's purpose is to display whatever data you bind to it. Using the **data binding** features often helps in constraining you into this passive form of display.

This means that you need some sort of **Controller** which can instantiate the View (Form) and bind the data source to it.

This is a lot easier to do with a technology such as WPF, but it's also possible with Windows Forms. For *inspiration* on how to do this with Windows Forms, I suggest that you take a look at the (now retired) [Composite Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx) - it's overly complicated, but it should give you some ideas on how to implement something similar yourself.

Comment: For VS designer compatibility, you can provide a private default constructor, and make your public constructor call the default one.

Comment: @Mark, I did some work with CAB a number of years ago - didn't hear that it was retired. Where did you find that it was retired?

Comment: @Eren Aygunes: Good point - I didn't know that. However, it doesn't really change my answer because from a design perspective, passive Views better fit the concept of a Control.

Comment: @mreith: Perhaps 'retired' is a bad choice of words, but remember that CAB was never a *product*. It's not being updated or evolved, mainly because Windows Forms as a technology isn't seeing much more evolution itself.

Comment: but what if you need dependencies in your UI? not heavy things, but things that are handy to swap out with test versions, such as a "message box provider" or "date provider"? if a control is supposed to default to a particular date value (today, this year), shouldn't I be injecting those dates somehow? the controls can be "dumb" relative to the DB, but I don't see how they can be completely "dumb", there has to be UI code. (maybe you'd say "bind the default date" but what if it's not a part of the model, only a part of the UI (ie: a filter)).

Comment: simplest example is a DateBox (my own custom control) that defaults to today. how do I get it to default to today without using `DateTime.Today` and without injecting an `IDateProvider`? (my answer so far is to use a ServiceLocator for the designer code (in my case a script (external DSL)). script code is already late-bound so a late-bound ServiceLocator should theoretically be ok).