# How should I be using IoC in this winform piece of code?

Tags: .net, winforms, inversion-of-control, structuremap, repository-pattern

I've got a winform app in visual studio 2010. My app does the following

- Get a list of files which I need to read the data then insert into a database.
- For each file, read data and insert into DB.

So .. this is the code i have.

```
// *******
// *** How should the _repository be Injected??
// *******
var list = _repository.GetFileList();
if (list != null)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(var file in list)
    {
       i++;
       var service = new MyService(i, _repository);
       service.ParseAndSave();
    }
}
```

So i was hoping to have a new repository for each 'service' i create.

Firstly, i'm not sure if I should be using IoC in this case. I believe I should be because then i don't need to tightly couple this winform to a repository.

Secondly, I've tried using a Singleton repo, which I don't want and can confirm that it kills that code (crashes with an exception).

Some other notes (which shouldn't impact this question)
  - Using Entity Framework for ASP.NET 4.
  - Using StructureMap for IoC

Can someone help, please?

#### UPDATE

Oh, I forgot to mention. When i don't specify the lifecycle type (eg. Singleton, etc). my objects which i try to save, just don't save. (ie nothing is sent to the DB, looking at SQL Profiler). If i use a Singleton with one file ... it works. A singleton with 2+ files, then exception/crashes because of (internal EF) Primary Key conflicts with Entity Framework. So if i should be using a Singleton, then the issue must be with how i've setup my EF4 context.

Comment: If you suspect your IOC configuration is incorrect, it would be helpful to post your configuration.

Comment: I didn't do that because I didn't want to influence an answer -> I was hoping someone would discuss what they have done in their own winform examples. Are there any SM examples of IoC with a winform which you might have doc'd somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two basic choices Constructor Injection (as in Mark Seemann's example) or Property (setter) injection (where supported by your container eg Unity)

In the case of a winform you either need to use Property (setter) injection which allows a default constructor to be used, or again as Mark suggests, using the form as just a simple renderer of data and in this case you should probably consider some variant of the [Model View Presenter pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/ModelViewPresenter.html)
(note in the link this pattern has been further refined and subdivided)

Its work taking a look at the sample code for the [MS Patterns and Practices Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) project for some examples which use MVP approach with Unity

Answer (score 0):

**Constructor Injection** is always a good start

```
public MyClass(IRepository repository)
{
    if(repository == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
    }

    this.repository = repository;
}
```

However, with Windows Forms, you run into the issue that your Form classes must have default constructors to support design-time functionality in Visual Studio. You can address this issue by making sure your [Forms are nothing more than dumb renderers of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209949/how-to-get-dependencies-injected-in-constructors-in-windows-forms/2210036#2210036).

Comment: Yep - that's all good .. and i do that with my WebForms/ASP.NET MVC apps... but with a winform? how (and with structuremap, for bonus points).... (and yep, i checked that link out). The main thing is.. i can't use Constructor Injection on the Form .. because in that form, each of my Files (i read) needs it's OWN repository .. not the one the Form will have/use.